# Filter XML on child tag in PHP and return parent tags

Tags: php, arrays, xml, dom, xpath

As the title states i have an XML that looks like below, with one account expanded to see the contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eExact
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-XML.xsd">
  <Accounts>
    <Account code="0" searchcode="" status="A" > </Account>
    <Account code="1" searchcode="" status="A" > </Account>
    <Account code="3" searchcode="" status="C" > </Account>
    <Account code="4" searchcode="" status="C" > </Account>
    <Account code="2" searchcode="" status="C" >
      <Name>Company 1</Name>
      <Phone>684564</Phone>
      <Email>info@company1.com</Email>
      <Contact number="2090075" gender="M" default="1" ID="{2449ce5d-41b3-4f80-bab3-d13f6687dfe4}">
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
        <Phone>44546456456e</Phone>
        <Email>tom.doe@company1.com</Email>
      </Contact>
      <Address type="SIV" default="1" ID="{41bde841-afde-4f5d-9cd0-a12ecf6f6777}">
        <AddressLine1>adress</AddressLine1>
        <PostalCode>10000</PostalCode>
        <City>TheCity</City>
        <Contact number="2090075" ID="{2449ce5d-41b3-4f80-bab3-d13f6687dfe4}" />
      </Address>
      <VATNumber>a_VAT_number_XXXX</VATNumber>
      <VATLiability>L</VATLiability>
      <SalesCurrency code="EUR" />
      <PurchaseCurrency code="EUR" />
    </Account>
  </Accounts>
  <Topics>
    <Topic code="Accounts" ts_d="0x000000006517487D" count="5" pagesize="1000" />
  </Topics>
  <Messages />
</eExact>
```

What i'm trying to do is return the accounts which have status C and contain a value in the VATNumber tags. Some of the accounts do not contain a value in VATNumber so i want those filtered out or not returned.

So far i managed to return the C accounts but without VATnumber filtering.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($response);
$xpath = new DOMxpath($document);


foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(/eExact/Accounts/Account[@status="C"])') as $account) { 

$json[] = [

   'email' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/Email)', $account),
    //'username' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
    'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
    'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
    'billing' => [
      'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
      'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
      'postcode'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(Address[@default="1"]/PostalCode)', $account),
      'VATNumber' => $xpath->evaluate('string(VATNumber)', $account),
    ],
    ];
    // ...
}



$customer = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$customers =   "{\"create\": {$customer} \t}";
// echo $customer;
echo $customers;
```

And it give me this output:

```
Key OK{"create": [
    {
        "email": "john.doe@company2.com",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "billing": {
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "postcode": "",
            "VATNumber": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "email": "steve.known@company3.com",
        "first_name": "Steve",
        "last_name": "Known",
        "billing": {
            "first_name": "Steve",
            "last_name": "Known",
            "postcode": "",
            "VATNumber": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "email": "tom.doe@company1.com",
        "first_name": "Tom",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "billing": {
            "first_name": "Tom",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "postcode": "9200",
            "VATNumber": "a_VAT_number_XXXX"
        }
    }
```

How do i do this sothat John and Steve do not show up since they have an Empty VAT number?

I assume i need to filter first before creating the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need is an if-statement testing if the value is `not empty`.

```
    if (!empty($xpath->evaluate('string(VATNUMBER)', $account))) {
        $json[] = [

        'email' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/Email)', $account),
         //'username' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
         'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
         'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
         'billing' => [
          'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
          'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
          'postcode'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(Address[@default="1"]/PostalCode)', $account),
          'VATNumber' => $xpath->evaluate('string(VATNumber)', $account),
         ],
        ];
        // ...
        }
    }
```

As long as my php isn't completely gone down the drain, encapsulating the `$json[] = [`  inside of an If-statement will test if that value is `empty` and if so, omit it from the results.

Answer (score 1):

You could expand your initial XPath expression to include checking for a non-empty vat number so that it only processes these elements...

```
/eExact/Accounts/Account[@status="C" and VATNumber/text()]
```

I would also initialise `$json` as if no records are, you get an undefined variable error further down.  So...

```
$json = [];
foreach ( $xpath->query('/eExact/Accounts/Account[@status="C" and VATNumber/text()]') as $account) {
```

Comment: Or `/eExact/Accounts/Account[@status="C" and normalize-space(VATNumber) != ""]`